# Best data Structure for storing a phone keypad format

Tags: java

I was trying to code the phone keypad characters with its numbers. The first idea which came to my mind is using a `HashMap`. After trying various options I came up with the below Code. I **want to know if the data structure and methodology which I implemented is good or does it need some more improvements.**

**Things which I know and don't want to implement:**

1. I do not want to hardcode the keypad. The reason for this is that since it was asked in timed-coding test so I don't want to write it again and again. I know that there are various ways of implementing a hardcoded keypad. I visited [**this**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/104879/creating-a-numeric-phone-keypad) and [**this**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90079/phone-keypad-implementation) link to learn about other ways.
2. I would really be thankful if the solution is given in java 7 syntax. I don't have much idea about java 8 syntax, but it'll be helpful to know the solution in that too, if possible.

**Keypad feature according to my problem statement:**

1. **0 and 1** buttons are not functional.
2. **7 and 9** buttons contain 4 letters each and **others** contain 3 letters each.

```java
public static void keypadDemo(){
        int ax = 97; // I need to store lower-case letters so took this
        Map<Integer, ArrayList<Character>> hm = new HashMap<>(); // This is my data-structure
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if(i == 0 || i == 1){
                hm.put(i, null); // 0 and 1 keys are not functional as per my problem statement.
            }else if(i == 7 || i == 9){
                hm.put(i, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList((char) ax, (char) ++ax, (char) ++ax, (char) ++ax)));
                ax++;
            }else{
                hm.put(i, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList((char) ax, (char) ++ax, (char) ++ax)));
                ax++;
            }
        }
       System.out.println(hm);
    }
```

Any help will be welcomed. Thanks

**EDIT:**

**Keypad format:**

[image: keypad format]

**The problem statement:**

1. We are given two inputs:

   - A phone number in string format.
   - A list of strings.
2. The output is the list containing only those strings which correspond to any substring of the given phone number when converted to the corresponding letters on the phone keypad.
3. **Example test case:**

```
Input: 
3662277
words = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "emo", "foobar", "cap", "car", "cat"]

Output: 
outputList = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "emo", "cap", "car"]
```

4. I coded the solution and it got accepted too by online judge. But since, I'm learning about `Collections` in java so wanted to know whether my choice of the data structure is up to the mark or not.

Comment: Wow, __great context-update__ to the question. Also your _contextual_ comment "time coding test" adds valuable rationale for the _design-decision_ to dynamically built the map in a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible to say if this method is a good or useful abstraction without context which you have not provided. Accordingly, this review is of the method by itself.

My primary concern with this method is that it is hard to read and understand. Complexity leads to bugs, and should be avoided where possible. This method is doing a simple thing in a complex way. Readers have to worry about a loop and three branches instead of a simple, static mapping.

`keypadDemo()` should return the Map, not print it. Let the client decide what to do with it.

`ax` and `hm` are very poor variable names. Variable names should clearly indicate the value they hold.

Using an integer to magically act as characters makes the method harder to read.

Use the most appropriate abstraction. `Map<Integer, List<Character>>` would be preferable. The type of list is an implementation detail.

A loop is the wrong structure to build this map. The code is hard to read, which means it's easy to introduce bugs and hard to notice them.

Short-circuiting the loop might make it easier to read.

Empty lists would be better than using `null`. It's easier to write code that correctly handles an empty list than to special-case null checks.

In idiomatic Java, there is whitespace before a { and after a }. There is whitespace after a `for`, `if`, etc.

If I were to need this method in my own code, it would look like: (untested)

```
/**
 * Generates a mapping from digits on a telephone keypad to the letters for 
 * digit. The letters are in alphabetical order. Digits with no letters
 * map to an empty list. 
 */
public static Map<Integer, List<Character>> digitsToCharacters() {
    Map<Integer, List<Character>> digitsToCharacters = new HashMap<>();
    digitsToCharacters.put(0, Arrays.asList());
    digitsToCharacters.put(1, Arrays.asList());
    digitsToCharacters.put(2, Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c'));
    digitsToCharacters.put(3, Arrays.asList('d', 'e', 'f'));
    digitsToCharacters.put(4, Arrays.asList('g', 'h', 'i'));
    digitsToCharacters.put(5, Arrays.asList('j', 'k', 'l'));
    digitsToCharacters.put(6, Arrays.asList('m', 'n', 'o'));
    digitsToCharacters.put(7, Arrays.asList('p', 'q', 'r', 's'));
    digitsToCharacters.put(8, Arrays.asList('t', 'u', 'v'));
    digitsToCharacters.put(9, Arrays.asList('w', 'x', 'y', 'z'));
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(digitsToCharacters);
}
```

Comment: My deepest apologies for using the variable names and the method not returning the `Map`. Actually, I know the importance of giving the proper variable names. It improves readability. I only needed assistance about the data-structure which I used, that is the reason I didn't focused on variable names. For **return type of the method also**, I know that I have to return the `Map`. But I was testing the code so kept it a void method and also added the same to this post.

Comment: One more doubt I have, please do clarify this also. Can I use this `Map` as a global `final` variable as mentioned in @hc_dev's answer. What performance issue I could face in doing so as compared to defining it inside a method?

Comment: Agree with everything. It would be possible use  the`Collections.emptyList` method instead of `Arrays.asList()` avoiding the creation of a new instance empty list but with the result of a a less flexible code.

Comment: **Empty lists would be better than using null** :: Y'all have no idea how true this is.Empty and non-empty lists ( collections in general actually ) can be handled with the same code.Adding a empty list-of-numbers is zero, the right answer; null means I have to read the %#$# code to find out why down-stream code threw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

Why would anyone use a Map to do a lookup which is keyed on the integers 0-9?

This is such an obvious use for an array. Untested code below...

```
List<Character>[] digitsToCharacters = new List<>[] {
     Arrays.asList(), // 0
     Arrays.asList(), // 1
     Arrays.asList('a', 'b', 'c'), // 2
     Arrays.asList('d', 'e', 'f'), // 3
     Arrays.asList('g', 'h', 'i'), // 4
     Arrays.asList('j', 'k', 'l'), // 5
     Arrays.asList('m', 'n', 'o'), // 6
     Arrays.asList('p', 'q', 'r', 's'), // 7
     Arrays.asList('t', 'u', 'v'), // 8
     Arrays.asList('w', 'x', 'y', 'z') // 9
   };
```

This should indicate that digitsToCharacters is an array, where each element is a list of characters. digitsToCharacters[2] is the list of characters corresponding to the number 2 on the keypad. This is simple and straightforward, represents the data in a natural way, and avoids the overheads of a Map.

My experience, over many years writing and maintaining code, is that clear code which represents the intent simply and directly is always preferable to more elaborate models - the idea of iterating from 0 to 9, but then doing different things on different values in the range is harder to read, comprehend and maintain than representing the data explicitly.

Beyond that, I'd echo other posters' comments about the magic number 97 - if you want to start at 'a' start at 'a' - and the unhelpful short names like 'ax'.

I don't understand the comment about "I do not want to hardcode the keypad" - this hardcodes a keypad, as all the mappings are explicitly stated in the code.

Personally if I were implementing this keypad lookup in Java, I'd consider using hardcoded values with switch statements. If the lookups were done enough times for performance to matter, the Just-In-Time compiler would almost certainly generate code that at least matched and quite possibly beat the implementations here.
If a data structure is needed, using an array would probably give the JIT enough information to generate good code, whereas using a Map hides the basically array-oriented processing and would probably make the JIT's job harder.

A final note to Mandy8055 - if you want good feedback on design, it's helpful to give more detail of what you are trying to achieve. For example in this case, explaining how you'd expect to use the data structure.
I note that the other examples you link to are concerned with mapping from letters to the corresponding keypad digit. The data structure you outline, and which we've attempted to improve on, does the opposite and if you wanted to go from letters to digits, it's almost certainly a poor choice.
For the latter case, I'd still be inclined to an array-based approach, using offsets from 'a' as my array index.

Comment: Agree: _indexed access_ would suffice  Even an array (besides `List`) could be initialized `static final` to store a _constant predefined_ and _only numerical_ keymap Start with KISS and keep most readable.

Comment: (a) Please don't start an answer by insulting other site members. (b) A map makes a promise about lookup performance that a List does not. To make a similar promise, you'd need a `char[][]`. (c) the merits of an ordered vs. unordered structure depends on the use cases that need to be supported. We have no information on that. (d) Your syntax is unclear. It looks like you're trying to make a `List<Character[]>`. Square brackets go inside the type declaration. It also looks like you're trying to implement the list inside an anonymous inner class, which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: **Why I didn't hardcoded the keypad?:** Actually, I had timed coding test. Less time was there and I had to solve more questions. Therefore, I found using loop would save some time instead of hardcoding the whole keypad.

Comment: @EricStein (a) I apologize for any offence caused, but I'd have said the same to any of my experienced java developer colleagues and would have been surprised if they were offended. (b) I'm not proposing a List - an array also gives performance promises and an array of 'List<Character>' is, in my opinion, the natural representation here. (c) ordered vs unordered is irrelevant when the key is an integer from a contiguous set. (d) my syntax is intended to denote that digitsToCharacters  is an array of 10 List<Character> objects, not a list of character arrays. Is that unclear?

Answer (score 2):

### Context drives Design

The use-case/purpose plays a pivotal role for designing (choosing datastructures and implementations).

Also the current situation & given constraints (like only Java-7, minimum time to code, test requires a method, etc.) can heavily reduce solution space and justify design-decisions as rational.

#### Assumptions & Constraints

- you require a **keymap** because you want to be able to react on *keypress events* from such a **numerical phone keypad**:
  [image: phone keypad]
- the keypad has following **number to character** mapping:
  [image: phone keys map number to characters]
- use this *keymap* later within a UI to react on keypress-events, e.g. by implementing a listener where numbers/keys pressed are translated to a letter-typed event

### Design choices

#### Datastructures

You can use several datastructures like

- accessed by a hash-value: `Map`
- accessed by a (numerical) index: `List` or simple Java array

#### Implementation details

.. as well as several implementations for these, based on your usage-scenarios within an application (threading, concurrency, ordered VS unordered, focus on insertion VS access, etc.).

Alongside the initialization and filling of these datastructures will vary with the chosen implementation. Supposed you are writing values (e.g. actual key-mapping) only once, then more important is the reading of values. This access usually needs to be fast (e.g. Event: a digit key was pressed. Which characters does it map to?).

You can compare this *trade-off* (write VS read) to the design and naming of source-code too: Code is written usually once, but read many times. Thus it is so important to have code-reviews to assure quality: comprehensible & readable code.

### Current implementation and issues

- the naming of the variables is hard to read (*proprietary abbreviations* like `hm` need prior knowledge of context or decryption)
- a *predefined* mapping (stated by your *given* restrictions) is **calculated dynamically** instead of declared as *static constant*

### Recommended improvement

Start simple and use a constant to represent the keymap as most readable.

```java
/**
 * A digit to character mapping as used on phone keypads.
 * <p>
 * The list's index has two essential purposes:
 *  (a) represents a key on a numerical keypad
 *  (b) serves as index to access elements of this list
 * </p>
 */
static final List<char[]> DIGIT_TO_CHARACTERS = Arrays.asList(
     new char[] {}, // 0
     new char[] {}, // 1
     new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'}, // 2
     new char[] {'d', 'e', 'f'}, // 3
     new char[] {'g', 'h', 'i'}, // 4
     new char[] {'j', 'k', 'l'}, // 5
     new char[] {'m', 'n', 'o'}, // 6
     new char[] {'p', 'q', 'r', 's'}, // 7
     new char[] {'t', 'u', 'v'}, // 8
     new char[] {'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'} // 9
);
```

Benefits:

- **readable**: clear readable mapping (datastructure initialization) and variable name `DIGIT_TO_CHARACTERS` (conveys intent as: *can map digit to (0 to many) characters*)
- **simply accessible**: *get* the characters represented by a given digit, like following examples:

  - digit 4 is mapped to `DIGIT_TO_CHARACTERS.get(4)` and will print as character sequence `ghi`
  - a single character can be derived by 0-based index, so that `DIGIT_TO_CHARACTERS.get(4)[0]` will get the single character `g`
- **performant**: because built at compile-time and static

See online [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/hRVZ7i).

#### Alternative char-array construction

Instead of `new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'}` you can also [construct a char-array from String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048899/string-to-char-array-java) like `"abc".toCharArray();`

Comment: Thank you @hc_dev for defining the data structure, `final` and `static`. Will surely add it.

Comment: @Mandy8055 appreciate :) Your comment lead me to a code-fix & update: (Java ideomatic) convention is to arrange modifiers in order [`static final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507602/how-can-i-initialise-a-static-map). So, thank you!

Comment: @Mandy8055 Headless HC's second fix: naming-conventions presrcibe [UPPERCASE for `static final`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259687/java-naming-convention-for-static-final-variables) a.k.a. constants.

Answer (score 2):

Now that @Mandy8055 has given a proper explanation of the use case, I've got a totally different perspective.

She says her problem statement is this:

1. We are given two inputs:

   A phone number in **string** format. (Mark: My emphasis)

   A list of strings.
2. The output is the list containing only those strings which correspond to any substring of the given phone number when converted to the corresponding letters on the phone keypad.

Example test case:

Input:
"3662277"

```
words = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "emo", "foobar", "cap", "car", "cat"]
```

Output:

```
outputList = ["foo", "bar", "foobar", "emo", "cap", "car"]
```

Given this problem statement, converting numbers to letters is not an approach I'd choose. I'd go the other way.

The key thing I notice is that the input set of digits is a String, so it's natural to treat it as such. You are never working with numbers here - you are working with characters, some of which are letters, others are digits.

If you map the list of words into the equivalent strings of digits (as characters, not numbers) you get (I think - I've done this quickly by hand) this list.

```
mappedWords = [ "366", "227", "229", "366", "366227","227", "227", "228" }
```

Each of which you can search for in the input string "3662277" using *String.contains()*.

You can take a number of approaches to look up digits for the letters. Neither of the examples you link to, which do this mapping, seem particularly elegant to me.

If you're particularly keen on using Maps, the natural one to use in this case would look something like this :

```
private static final Map<Character, Character> letterToDigit = new HashMap<>;
letterToDigit.put('a', '2');
letterToDigit.put('b', '2');
```

etc...

I'd be equally inclined to use a switch statement for the mapping - here's an outline of a method to turn an input letter to an output digit. It's incomplete, and you may wish to consider how you deal with out-of-range input:

```
private static char digitFromLetter(char letter) {
  switch(letter) {
    case 'a':
    case 'b':
    case 'c':
      return '2';
    case 'd':
    case 'e':
    case 'f':
      return '3';
    ...
  }
}
```

Some may challenge the performance of this approach, but a) I'm not convinced performance is important in this particular case and b) I'd wager that a JIT compiler would make it perform perfectly well anyway.

You could also look at an array-based approach, outlined here, but incomplete and needing error handling:-

```
private static final char[] digit = new char[] {
  '2', '2', '2',         // abc
  '3', '3', '3',         // def
   ...
};

private static char digitFromLetter(char letter) {
  return digit[letter - 'a'];
}
```

Hope this is helpful and interesting.

Edit: I had some free time and access to an IDE, so here's my solution to the stated problem.

```
package keypad;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Keypad {

  private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(selectWords("3662277", new String[]{"foo", "bar", "baz", "emo", "foobar", "cap", "car", "cat"}));
  }

  /**
   * @param letter
   * @return the corresponding digit on a telephone keypad
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the letter isn't in the alphabet
   */
  private static char letterToDigit(char letter) {
    switch (Character.toLowerCase(letter)) {
      case 'a' :
      case 'b' :
      case 'c' :
        return '2';
      case 'd' :
      case 'e' :
      case 'f' :
        return '3';
      case 'g' :
      case 'h' :
      case 'i' :
        return '4';
      case 'j' :
      case 'k' :
      case 'l' :
        return '5';
      case 'm' :
      case 'n' :
      case 'o' :
        return '6';
      case 'p' :
      case 'q' :
      case 'r' :
      case 's' :
        return '7';
      case 't' :
      case 'u' :
      case 'v' :
        return '8';
      case 'w' :
      case 'x' :
      case 'y' :
      case 'z' :
        return '9';
      default :
        // Bad value - we'll simply throw an unchecked exception in this example
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("The input '%s' is not in the range 'a' - 'z'", letter));
    }
  }

  /**
   * @param word - a word
   * @return the string of digits corresponding to that word
   */
  private static String digitise(String word) {
    StringBuffer digitisedWord = new StringBuffer(word.length());
    for (int characterIndex = 0; characterIndex < word.length(); characterIndex++) {
      digitisedWord.append(letterToDigit(word.charAt(characterIndex)));
    }
    return digitisedWord.toString();
  }

  /**
   * @param words
   * @return the words, remapped to their keypad digit representations
   */
  private static String[] digitise(String[] words) {
    String[] digitisedWords = new String[words.length];
    for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words.length; wordIndex++) {
      digitisedWords[wordIndex] = digitise(words[wordIndex]);
    }
    return digitisedWords;
  }

  /**
   * @param words candidate words to be checked
   * @param digitisedWords corresponding "digitised" words
   * @param digits a string of digits to be searched for the digitised words
   * @return all words for which their digitised version could be found in "digits"
   */
  private static List<String> filter(String[] words, String[] digitisedWords, String digits) {
    List<String> filteredWords = new ArrayList<>(); // List rather than array as we can't predict the actual size
    for (int wordIndex = 0; wordIndex < words.length; wordIndex++) {
      if (digits.contains(digitisedWords[wordIndex])) {
        filteredWords.add(words[wordIndex]);
      }
    }
    return filteredWords;
  }

  /**
   * Check a list of words against a sequence of digits
   * @param digits
   * @param words
   * @return all words which could be represented in the sequence of digits
   */
  public static List<String> selectWords(String digits, String[] words) {
    if (DEBUG) {
      System.out.format("Searching for %s in %s%n", Arrays.toString(words), digits);
    }

    String[] digitisedWords = digitise(words);

    if (DEBUG) {
      System.out.format("Remapped the words to %s%n", Arrays.toString(digitisedWords));
    }

    return filter(words, digitisedWords, digits);
  }
}
```

Comment: Given the update, the switch solution here is what I would go with.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, there are many ways to archive your purpose, your idea of using a Hash structure is really nice, also selecting [`HashMap` over `Hashtable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html) is a good thing in java

> As of the Java 2 platform v1.2, this class was retrofitted to implement the Map interface, making it a member of the Java Collections Framework. Unlike the new collection implementations, Hashtable is synchronized. If a thread-safe implementation is not needed, it is recommended to use **HashMap** in place of **Hashtable**. If a thread-safe highly-concurrent implementation is desired, then it is recommended to use **ConcurrentHashMap** in place of **Hashtable**.

Also, a hashed structure as we know has \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ average access time.

Regarding the implementation, it's hard to tell how to improve your actual code. Perhaps the following modification could help:

```java
public static void keypadDemo() {
    int ax = 97;
    Map<Integer, ArrayList<Character>> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put(0, null);
    hm.put(1, null);
    for(int i = 2; i < 10; i++) {
        if (i == 7 || i == 9)
            hm.put(i, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList((char) ax++, (char) ax++, (char) ax++, (char) ax++)));
        else hm.put(i, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList((char) ax++, (char) ax++, (char) ax++)));
    }
    System.out.println(hm);
}
```

The difference consists of not checking the statement `if (i == 0 || i == 1)` all the times the loop does an iteration, offcourse it's nearly no improvement but there's no much to do.

Another option (though ugly) is to insert each `key, value` pair into the Map, it implies to not create the for loop, the iteration variable `i` and to avoid comparisons `i < 10` and `(i == 7 || i == 9)` in the loop.

Comment: Strongly discourage to engage performance-considerations as long as not an issue! Primary goal of each software/code should be (a) functionality & (b) usability/readability.
BTW: optimize performance by either implementing the mapping as (switch-based) key-listener as [suggested by M.Blumel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/256290/127399). This is common UI-best-practice. Alternatively declare the mapping as `static` constant.